# SQL query doesn't return what I expected

Tags: sql, ms-access

First and foremost, thank you so much for taking the time to look at my SQL issue.  I'm building a query MS Access and I'm pulling my hair out because I can't figure out what the heck is wrong with my query!

```
SELECT First(StoreNum) AS FirstOfStoreNum, 
       NewItem, ItemNum, Wrin, TotalUnits, Avg(UnitAmt) AS AvgOfUnitAmt 
FROM qryPhyInvGTZeroWithUnitPrice 
GROUP BY NewItem, ItemNum, Wrin, TotalUnits;
```

All I want from this stupid query is the average unit amount of all like NewItems.  Please gurus!  I need your help. What am I missing?

This is an excerpt of what is being returned when I run this query.  There should be 20 stores for this [NewItem], but there are only 19 being returned.

[image]

I hope this helps better explain my question.

UPDATE!!!
I needed just step away from it.  I re-read the answers and you guys were right (of course).  Here's the updated code.

```
SELECT StoreNum, NewItem, ItemNum, Wrin, Avg(UnitAmt) AS AvgOfUnitAmt
FROM qryPhyInvGTZeroWithUnitPrice
GROUP BY StoreNum, NewItem, ItemNum, Wrin;
```

I also got rid of the total units, because it wasn't beneficial to this project.  The query works like it should after implementing your tips!  Thanks again!

Comment: How is what you're getting wrong?  Can you give an example of what you want to get and what you get instead?

Comment: I'm following certain [NewItems] and how many stores ([StoreNum]) have these [NewItems].  When I run this query, the list of stores which carry these NewItem is correct, but there are a couple of stores missing from other groups of NewItems.  I hope this helps.

Comment: I'm confused by the phrase "the list of stores". This query will only show one `StoreNum` value per unique value of `NewItem`, `ItemNum`, `Wrin`, and `TotalUnits`. If there are two records that have the same values for those 3 fields you're grouping on, only one record will appear, with whatever `StoreNum` value it happened to hit first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need to add is the `qryPhyInvGTZeroWithUnitPrice.StoreNum` to your `Group By` and it should work.  Calling an aggregate function like `AVG` with either another aggregate function or group by will cause a failed query.

**Edit:**
The data you are getting back appears to be that of items and not `StoreNum`s.  I would say you have 19 different combinations of `NewItem, ItemNum, Wrin, TotalUnits` in the one `StoreNum`.

Comment: The query isn't failing.  `qryPhyInvGTZeroWithUnitPrice.StoreNum` is in the `First` aggregate function.

Comment: Try the `group by` suggestion, it will probably work. `First` will possibly aggregate stores out depending on the data in the other columns. `Group by` will not.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT First(StoreNum) AS FirstOfStoreNum, 
       NewItem, ItemNum, Wrin, TotalUnits, Avg(UnitAmt) AS AvgOfUnitAmt 
FROM qryPhyInvGTZeroWithUnitPrice 
GROUP BY StoreNum, NewItem, ItemNum, Wrin, TotalUnits;
```